# My script works fine on static content, but breaks when the content is changed via AJAX - jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I am writing a custom calendar, that consists of two parts, one div showing the month grid, and a second div showing the events for the selected date. The current month's calendar grid loads automatically, and the display of daily events works correctly. However, when the user clicks the button to view the next or previous month, clicking on the dates no longer works. Also, changing the month no longer works on the dynamically-loaded calendar.

This is the jQuery code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(

    function() {
        $('div.calendar_events').text('To view the events on any of the highlighted dates, simply click the date.');
        $('div.number').click(

        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var theDate = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
            $('div.calendar_events').load('ajax/calendar_events.php?month=' + theDate[1] + '&day=' + theDate[2] + '&year=' + theDate[3]);
        });
        $('a.changemonth').click(

        function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var theDate = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
            $('div.calendar').load('ajax/calendar_view.php?month=' + theDate[1] + '&year=' + theDate[2]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't setup the events directly using `click`. Use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead.

```
$('div.number').live('click', function() { .. });
```

When the new AJAX content loads, the new content replaces the old and also wipes out all event handlers you previously attached to that replaced content using `bind` or its shortcut methods such as `click`, `change`, etc.

Live event handlers, on the other hand, are added to the document and due to the event bubbling in the DOM, all events eventually reach up to the document (which you never replace, or ideally should never replace :), so you can think of `document` as a safe-haven for adding events.

Also checkout [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) which is another way to make use of event bubbling, especially if you are a performance freak.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method of jQuery instead of `click` for any content that is generated dynamically, here is an example:

```
$('selector').live('click', function(){
   // your code....
});
```

**.live()**

> Attach a handler to the event for all
>   elements which match the current
>   selector, now or in the future.